# How do I get my "Personal Stereo"?

Tags: lone-survivor

To get the Muso trophy you need to get a "Personal Stereo" item (or walkman) and listen to it. This item is hinted at outside of the record store but I haven't obtained it in 5 playthroughs after getting all endings. How do I get the Personal Stereo? And, if it's not as easy as just selecting "use" in the menu, how do I listen to it for the trophy?

Answer (score 1):

I got it from The Director at the end of my 3rd playthrough after giving him all of the Garfield comics. I was going for the White ending so I had given the cat to everyone. Hope this helps.

Comment: I could swear I did that, but maybe my mental health wasn't high enough. Did you eat the burger before the director left?